# onClick get value of element and pass value to next view/component as url in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, jsx, react-router-dom

How do you get the value of a `<tr>` onClick and move to the next view/component using that value  passed into the url? For example, the user is on `/contacts` and the `<tr value="123456">` onClick how do you goto `/contacts/123456`? Expected url `contacts/:id`

**react-router-dom routes**

```
<Route exact path="/contacts" component={Contacts} />
<Route exact path="/contacts/:id" component={ContactDetails} />
<Route exact path="/contacts/new" component={ContactNew} />
```

**React Component**

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { fetchContacts } from "../../actions";

class ContactList extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.fetchContacts();
    }

    renderContacts() {
        return this.props.contacts.reverse().map(contact => {
            return (
                <tr 
                    key={contact._id} 
                    value={contact._id}
                    onClick={...} // ???
                    onClick={() => {window.location.href = `contacts/${contact._id}`}} // works but better way?
                >
                    <td>{contact.firstname}</td>
                    <td>{contact.lastname}</td>
                    <td>{contact.mobile}</td>
                    <td>{contact.email}</td>
                </tr>
            )
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Fragment>
                {this.renderContacts()}
            </Fragment>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps({ contacts }) {
    return { contacts };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchContacts })(ContactList);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the following arrow function to onClick:

```
  import history from './history.js'

  ()=> history.push(`contact/${contact._id}`)
```

You will need to npm i history and create a history.js file:

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';
const history = createBrowserHistory();
export default history;
```

Then import it into your index.js and configure as:

```
import history from './history.js'
import {Router} from 'react-router-dom'

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Router history={history}>
            <App />
        </Router>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
)
```

Note: the path to your history.js will vary depending on your folder structure

Comment: if I have protected routes should I wrap the portion of app that has access in `<Router history={history}>` or is it safe to put on the outside of the `<App />` as a whole?

Comment: You can, I'm not too sure if it makes any difference though. As long as all the routes are nested in <Router> it should work the same; the official redux docs show it as I did in my answer.